# Transform translate in react native moves element under others no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

Here is sandbox: https://snack.expo.dev/@nik96/sandbox-react-native

I just want to make simple animation with translate, but I don't understand why when I move element right and down it goes under other elements, but if left and up then is ok. How it can even be like this? It's literally same thing just different directions. I have this problem only with react native. Normal react, js or even just css don't have this problem. I don't know what to do, I tried zIndex, absolute position, react native reanimated which does same thing. I couldn't fix it and didn't find something about it in google. Please help.

Comment: please give the details about what you need to achieve, I had seen your code but element is not animating any side.

Comment: It's not animated yet, I just moved it little bit to show that it goes under other elements. If you translate it more, it will just complete hidden. Just play with translate parameter where is <View style={[styles.activeCell, {transform: [{ translateX: 40 }]}]}> and you will see that -40 works fine and moves element above others, but 40 not. I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

This a hack, but ... work with the flow:

```
.r-18u37iz {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: this will mess up everything because there will be more cells with numbers, I'm trying to make 2048 game, I can't just reverse whole row